# ArcGIS Online error when downloading area for offline use: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: arcgis-online, offline

I configured a Sweet for ArcGIS application that works great in a browser. Nevertheless, we will need to enable the offline mode as well, since our field workers will be working in fairly remote areas.

When I try to download the application for offline use, I get an error:

> Error: Exporting Feature Gdb (link of the feature service that causes
> an issue)
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Stack: Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

There are 2 layers in that feature service and I narrowed it down to which one is problematic, as the app downloads fine if I remove the layer causing issue.

I double checked the offline configuration many times to make sure everything is set as it should be, there are no special characters in field names either. I created new layer with the same schema and it fails as well, hence I assume it might be something wrong with the configuration of the fields?

Any idea what the error above could relate to?